# Multiple resource parameters in 'Query' resource for getting results in messaging paradigm

Tags: hl7-fhir

I want to use Query resource to get list of documents back from repository in binary format. Repository maintains Document Reference resource and Patient details. My parameters are based on

1. DocumentReference.type
2. DocumentReference.subject.Patient.identifier.value@value
3. DocumentReference.subject.Patient.identifier.system@value

This is what my guess the parameters will look like -

```
<parameter url="http://nhs.uk/fhir/query#_type">
  <valueString value="DocumentReference"/>
</parameter>
<parameter url="http://nhs.uk/fhir/query#type">
  <valueString value="EndofLifeCareRecord"/>
</parameter>
<parameter url="http://nhs.uk/fhir/query#subject:Patient.identifier.value">
  <valueString value="12345"/>
</parameter>
<parameter url="http://nhs.uk/fhir/query#subject:Patient.identifier.system">
  <valueString value="http://nhs.uk/fhir/nhs-number/"/>
</parameter>
```

My Questions -

1. Is the above parameter construct correct considering that I am using message paradigm (not REST)?
2. How response will be constructed, i.e. Document Resource will be populated with subject (i.e. Patient). Will it be a contained resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using the parameters defined in the specification, then the URL for them is http://hl7.org/fhir/query. If you are defining the parameters yourself - which seems to be case for 3 of 4 of them (is that what you meant to do?) then you provide your own namespace, as you have. The format of the parameters is correct.

In terms of the response, it's a bundle with a message header resource, and a query resource that contains references to the resources that constitute the result set for the query, and those resources must be in the bundle. The document resource refers to the subject (patient) by URL, and you have 3 choices for where to put the patient resource:

1. contained in the document reference resource
2. in the bundle
3. on a server elsewhere

I think that #3 doesn't work in your case, so you pick between #1 and #2. Contained resources are always a bad idea - they handicap subsequent usage of the resource by de-identifying it. So you should only ever use contained resources when you have to, because you don't have enough information to construct an identified resource - and that would be a very bad idea for your patient resource. Very bad idea indeed.

Comment: So if option #2 is chosen and a patient resource is included in the bundle then for the purposes of the query it's only job is to carry the patient identifier. It cannot be a complete representation of the  patient.

Comment: umm, because why? I don't see why it can't be the normal patient resource that represents the patient

Comment: The system sending the query may have a completely different information model for demographics than the system fulfilling the query, even there the models are the same the content may be different. The only place where the overlap between the two different perspectives on "patient" exist are the parameters in the query, in this case the "id". If the supplied patient resource has additional information in it then what purpose does it serve? What could the fulfilling system hope to do with that information?

Comment: So it can be the normal patient resource. You just think that there's not a lot of point in the use case - well, ok. Though in the general case, that's not always true. Maybe the user entered the id directly, and the system initiating the query doesn't have any information. Or maybe the system responding to the query is required to do a 3 point identity check. Or maybe it will display the responder's demographics as well as it's own. So there maybe utily in returning the extra information. But it's not true to say that "it *cannot* be a complete representation of the patient"